# React and Liferay portal routing difference

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, liferay, portal

My thoughts are that a problem is in the routing differences between these two.

The application works when I serve it on localhost:3000 and the whole front-end is presented, but when I build the application using mvn package and upload the .war file to the Liferay Portal, I am presented with only the navigation bar.

Also when I press on any element in the navbar, nothing happens. Neither in the console, network or on the URL. If someone has any clues it would mean a lot to me.

Thank you.

Comment: please edit your question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @OlafKock okay maybe my question doesn't explain it well, but the URL doesn't change at all at the click of a navbar button. Can you maybe provide a piece of code or an explanation on how to generate the URL from the click of a nav button. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamJozic Did you add your portlet to the theme via right panel ? If no you should add it first to see it.

Comment: You say "maybe my question doesn't explain it well" but still expect an answer? Seriously?  I don't even know if your problem is on the Liferay or React side based on this description. Thus the [mcve].

Comment: As it turns out the problem was that the Portal was loading the old version of the application. I restarted the browser cache and the complete docker.

Answer (score 0):

This question needs some clarification about the source code and what did you use
But maybe you are using the BrowseRouter rather than HashRouter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).